# How to access multiframe index for plotting per table columns

Tags: pgfplots, plot, animate

I would like to animate 3d plot where plotting data are in table.
They are ordered as follows

```
\begin{filecontents}{AA}
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
0.1  0   0.4   0.1 0   0.4
0.3  0   0.12   0.3 2 1                  
...
\end{filecontents}
```

One frame should be the first column triple, `x1 x2 x3` and another `x4 x5 x6` (as `x,y,z`).

But I cant get through the indexing of frames.

```
\begin{animateinline}[controls, palindrome]{6} % frames per second  
  \multiframe{}{n=1+1}{ %frames with \n running 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        ticks = none,
        axis lines = middle]
            \addplot3[smooth, ultra thin, mark=none] table[x=x\n, y=x2, z=x3] {AA};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }  
\end{animateinline}
```

I tried defining new variables for indexing `y` and `z` but I was not able to calculate them according to multiframe variable `\n`.

Can you seuggest another approach or something?

MWE:

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{animate}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{AA}
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
   4.904580240000000  -2.974098630000000  -6.444943280000000   4.210292740000000  -2.873583600000000  -0.487057700000000
   5.004457720000000  -3.509494060000000  -0.330922790000000   3.257552530000000  -3.117999570000000   7.631587500000000
   3.675409580000000  -3.754664270000000  11.124269730000000   1.120766430000000  -2.882311810000000  13.433930159999999
   0.816333360000000  -3.365484110000000  17.732776399999999  -1.118058130000000  -2.106595390000000  10.088750320000001
  -1.976809280000000  -2.303012750000000  12.384788170000000  -2.401139500000000  -1.073269810000000   4.122039400000000
  -3.504589980000000  -0.958277850000000   5.260611890000000  -2.837346870000000  -0.100669260000000   1.094804940000000
  -4.063569710000000   0.288000330000000   2.238588260000000  -2.908293130000000   0.673806950000000   0.813779400000000
  -4.265831590000000   1.296414800000000   2.483840180000000  -2.965784480000000   1.258517390000000   2.069885150000000
  -4.500883010000000   2.095326500000000   4.129450120000000  -3.177693360000000   1.725889690000000   3.733646770000000
  -4.831611350000000   2.763799770000000   4.736467900000000  -3.537237910000000   2.149235240000000   4.732940120000000
\end{filecontents}
    
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{animate bifurcation}
    \centering
    \begin{animateinline}[controls, palindrome]{6} % frames per second  
      \multiframe{2}{n=1+1}{ %frames with \n running 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
            ticks = none,
            axis lines = middle]
                \addplot3[smooth, ultra thin, mark=none] table[x=x\n, y=x2, z=x3] {AA};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
      }  
    \end{animateinline}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: There is no number of animation frames to be produced (first arg of `\multiframe` is empty). Does it compile at all?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second argument of `\multiframe`, as many parameters as needed can be defined:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{AA.dat}
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6
4.904580240000000  -2.974098630000000  -6.444943280000000   4.210292740000000  -2.873583600000000  -0.487057700000000
5.004457720000000  -3.509494060000000  -0.330922790000000   3.257552530000000  -3.117999570000000   7.631587500000000
3.675409580000000  -3.754664270000000  11.124269730000000   1.120766430000000  -2.882311810000000  13.433930159999999
0.816333360000000  -3.365484110000000  17.732776399999999  -1.118058130000000  -2.106595390000000  10.088750320000001
1.976809280000000  -2.303012750000000  12.384788170000000  -2.401139500000000  -1.073269810000000   4.122039400000000
3.504589980000000  -0.958277850000000   5.260611890000000  -2.837346870000000  -0.100669260000000   1.094804940000000
4.063569710000000   0.288000330000000   2.238588260000000  -2.908293130000000   0.673806950000000   0.813779400000000
4.265831590000000   1.296414800000000   2.483840180000000  -2.965784480000000   1.258517390000000   2.069885150000000
4.500883010000000   2.095326500000000   4.129450120000000  -3.177693360000000   1.725889690000000   3.733646770000000
4.831611350000000   2.763799770000000   4.736467900000000  -3.537237910000000   2.149235240000000   4.732940120000000
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{animate bifurcation}
\centering
\begin{animateinline}[controls, palindrome]{6} % frames per second  
  \multiframe{2}{nx=1+3,ny=2+3,nz=3+3}{ %frames with \n running 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,xmax=6,
        ymin=-4,ymax=3,
        zmin=-7,zmax=18,
        ticks = none,
        axis lines = middle]
            \addplot3[smooth, ultra thin, mark=none] table[x=x\nx, y=x\ny, z=x\nz] {AA.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is really powerful, thank you for such a nice solution